# Getting CORS error in Angular even though access-control-allow-origin and other headers are set to "*" in server side

Tags: .net, cors

I am using Angular in Frontend and Dotnet in Backend of the application. In backend api configuration, I am allowing any type of origin, header and method, but while making an http request to the backend API, i am getting CORS error in browser.

In frontend, i have no configuration for proxy server, it's a plain http request with httpClient of angular.

[image: Frontend Http request call]

In backend the code is like this :

[image: Dot net api config]

CORS error in browser :
[image: CORS error in browser]

My confusion is, even though i am allowing any type of http request header,method, origin in my API, why should it still cause CORS error in browser. Any workaround for this will be a great help.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you set in configureservice method but need to add in configure method.

What i did

1. one project, i have added the below lines `configure method of startup.cs`

```
 app.UseCors(x => x
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader());
```

2. In other project, added in configure and configureservice method of startup as well as.

In `configure method of startup.cs`

```
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
app.UseCors("AllowAllHeaders");
```

and in `ConfigureService Method`

```
services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod();
                      });
            });
```

Comment: what is wrong in my answer? Please suggest me